# Traducción: "America or burst"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

No sé a santo de qué ha venido hace poco a mi memoria el recuerdo de la serie *Perfect Strangers* (titulada *Primos Lejanos* en España). Aún recuerdo como de pequeño, al ver los títulos de crédito, me desconcertaba el "América or Burst" que se lee en la caja con las pertenencias de Balki Bartokomous cuando deja la isla de Mypos camino de América.

Recuerdo ir al diccionario hasta encontrar "Burst" (explotar, estallar).

> (of a container) break suddenly and violently apart, spilling the contents, typically as a result of an impact or internal pressure.

Y preguntarme, "América o *explortar*? Significa eso algo así como "Mandar a América o tirar por el camino si no se puede"? "A América o deshacerse de esto?" "A América o a la basura"?

Cuál sería una traducción acertada para "América or Burst"?

[image: Balki]

Comment: ¡Interesante! Leo en http://www.oocities.org/unincompoop/shocking4.html `meaning that if Balki does not get to America, his intestines will burst. Either simply from disappointment or that month old Myposian wheat bread Mama Bartokomous gave him!`

Comment: Ahora no puedo quitarme de la cabeza la canción de los Bibbi babka >:(

Comment: @guillem, "Si sonríes al pastel, Bibbi Babka sale bien". Mejor que la "_Danza de la alegría_", que sólo tenía por letra "Dai dai dai dai, la la la la lai..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La expresión es usualmente "*loquesea* [or bust](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/or+bust)", significa "*loquesea* o morir en el intento", y se popularizó aparentemente durante la [Fiebre del Oro](http://mentalfloss.com/article/60989/why-do-hitchhikers-say-destinationor-bust). No he visto la serie que mencionas, pero ha de ser un juego de palabras que hace referencia a la (según [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balki_Bartokomous)) ignorancia que el personaje tiene sobre la cultura estadounidense.

Comment: Eso es correcto. "America or Burst" es un error intencional, en carácter con Balki, quien siempre dice las frases populares un poco incorrectas.